# Executing shell command in php doesn't work

Tags: php, macos, shell, terminal, imagemagick

I'm trying to execute a shell script to convert some images from .png to .tif using the command convert.

I have written a short shell script:

```
#! /bin/bash
convert -adaptive-resize 150% /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/1.png /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/1.tif
convert -adaptive-resize 150% /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/2.png /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/2.tif
convert -adaptive-resize 150% /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/3.png /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/3.tif
convert -adaptive-resize 150% /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/4.png /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/4.tif
convert -adaptive-resize 150% /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/5.png /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/5.tif
convert -adaptive-resize 150% /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/6.png /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/6.tif
convert -adaptive-resize 150% /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/7.png /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/7.tif
convert -adaptive-resize 150% /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/8.png /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/8.tif
convert -adaptive-resize 150% /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/9.png /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/9.
```

If I run this script from the terminal it works as expected.

Instead if I launch this from whithin a php page it doesn't.

I'm using this code:

```
exec("bash /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/convertpngtif.sh");
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: When you launch it from within a php page, do you get any error messages?

Comment: The user PHP runs as probably doesn't have permissions to access that script.

Comment: Try this : shell_exec("bash/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/convertpngtif.sh");

Comment: @TecBrat No I don't get any error message

Comment: @vascowhite I'm sure that's the problem, how can I solve this?

Comment: @Rohit The only difference I can see between `exec()` and `shell_exec()` is how they return the output of the program.

Comment: @Rohit Doens't work either.

Comment: Try `echo shell_exec(...)`, so you see the output of the script. This way you'll see any error messages it produces.

Comment: @Barmar No errors produced.

Comment: @Giorgio I can see space between bash & /.So remove space & try

Comment: However I will run the script locally so I'm not concerned with security issues: so feel free to suggest solutions that imply making the file/folder executable and writable by everyone in the world :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: use full path in the shell script.

Answer (score 1):

This is a permissions problem. You need to allow the user that PHP runs as to have access to the sh file.

PHP usually runs as www-data, that being the case you can open a terminal and run something like:-

```
chown www-data:www-data /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/convertpngtif.sh
```

I don't know how your system is set up, so you may have to sudo that command.

You will have to make sure that www-data also has access to the files accessed by the bash script in a similar way, so just the following command may work:-

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/
```

Comment: chown: www-data: Invalid argument

Comment: Ah, sorry I thought you were on Linux. Didn't spot the OSX tag, what a duffer! Can't help any further, sorry. Although it looks as if the syntax is the same http://ss64.com/osx/chown.html